# Should you include your collaborations in your CV?

Tags: cv, collaboration

Should you create a section listing your research collaborations in your CV?

If yes, should you name of collaborators (who might not be known to the audience) or list the institutions and their countries with which you have collaborated?

Comment: Usually this is shown implicitly by listing the other authors of your papers in your "Publications" section.  I've never seen a separate section used.  Collaborations that didn't lead to papers are usually not something to brag about.

Comment: NSF biographical sketches require you to list collaborators, students advised, postdocs, etc. for purposes of determining who would have conflict in reviewing your proposal.  That's not an ordinary part of a CV, but it is something that's needed in the context of applying for an NSF grant.  It can be very painful to keep such a list up to date, because names on the list "age-out" after a certain time and should be removed.

Comment: @NateEldredge how one can find collaborations from list of authors? Co-authors can be my students and co-workers in my group or department. How to show that I am a collaborative person with international collaborations?

Comment: **All** co-authors are collaborators.

Comment: What Kimball said. In particular, your students are collaborators.

Answer (score 1):

For the main question, you may to include the list of collaborations in your CV. Although it could be inferred from your publications, not all collaborations have the need to be published, especially in the case of classified projects such as the ones funded by your nation's defense research department.

From the arguments from the comments, it is clear that co-authors are considered to be collaborators. In some cases, all of your co-authors may not hold considerable contribution and certain collaborators you wish to show are not in the list of co-authors of your papers. Hence, you may include a *Major Collaborators* list in your CV and cover those whom you think are important collaborators you have worked with.

Comment: Isaac I agree with you. Just highlight the prestige collaborators in your CV to promote your works.